# "The syntax of the command (arithm expression) is incorrect" in nested "IF" statement in batch

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, arithmetic-expressions

I'm writing a batch file right now and encountered a problem. I need to make "OR" statement in "AND" statement in batch script.
Here's my code:

```
@echo off
set /p a="a="
set /p b="b="
if "%a%" == "5" (
    if "%b%" == "8" (
        set /a "c=%a%*%b%"
        goto :win 
    )
    if "%b%" == "2"(
        set /a "c=%a%+%b%"
        goto :win 
    )   
)
goto :fail
:win
echo %c%
goto :exit
:fail
echo U'r not a magician!
:exit
pause
```

The problem is that it only works fine without second nested "IF" expression but I need a possibility of getting both results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine when you insert a `SPACE` between `"2"` and `(`.

The line that is causing problem is:

```
if "%b%" == "2"(
```

To fix, change the code to:

```
if "%b%" == "2" (
```

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've accepted your answer, I'd just like to mention that your code seems OTT, because you already know the accepted parameters and what you're going to do with them. *(There isn't really a need to perform the arithmetic operations)*. This structure would act in the same manner:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set/P "a=a="
Set/P "b=b="
Set "c="

If "%a%][%b%"=="5][8" Set "c=40"
If "%a%][%b%"=="5][2" Set "c=7"

If Defined c (Echo=%c%) Else (Echo=U'r not a magician!)

Pause
```